# Sharing a list between threads in C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am having a problem with sharing a list between 2 or more threads at C++. I initialize my list in main() and then create the threads, passing the list object pointer as argument:

```
pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &threadfunction, &l);
```

where `&l` is the argument. Is this the correct way to manipulate the same list from 2 or more threads? I use a simple mutex for locking/unlocking, so no more than one thread is accessing it at a time.

EDIT: code below

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include "list.h" 

using namespace std;
int count = 0;
pthread_t tid[2]; 
pthread_mutex_t lock; 

void* trythis(void *arg) 
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
    printf("Starting thread\n");
    count++;
    printf("%d\n", count);
    if(count == 1)
    {
        ((list *)arg)->Append((char *)"some", (char *)"thing");
        printf("Appending done\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ((list *)arg)->Append((char *)"some", (char *)"else");
        printf("Appending done\n");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 

    return NULL; 
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
    list* l = new list();
    int i = 0; 
    printf("Starting\n");
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) 
    { 
        printf("mutex init has failed\n"); 
        return 1; 
    } 

while(i < 2) 
{ 
    int err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &trythis, &l); 
    if (err != 0) 
        printf("\nThread can't be created :[%s]", strerror(err)); 
    i++; 
} 

pthread_join(tid[0], NULL); 
printf("Im out 1\n");
pthread_join(tid[1], NULL); 
printf("Im out 2\n");

pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); 

delete l;
return 0;
```

}

---

The Append() function is just adding some elements in the list ( every list Node has 2 char* members).

Comment: Do you have to use `pthread`?  C++11+ comes with built in thread support that is type safe and lets you get away from all the casts and `void*`'s that `pthread` uses.

Comment: yes, i have to use pthread sadly

Comment: Show the other parts of your code. As long as the list doesn't go out of scope this is fine.

Comment: This will create the thread, but to tell you whether or not you have the synchronization correct, we'll need to see the synchronization code.

Comment: @FraPapas on Linux std::thread uses pthread, so technically you are using it. Homework requirement?

Comment: Locking a list with a single mutex is a bad and not effective practice. I would advise you to read the book of Anthony Williams "C++ Concurrency in Action". That is not an answer to you question (because that would be a huge quote from the book), but that is the best recommendation that could be given. The book worth the time spent. https://www.cplusplusconcurrencyinaction.com/

Comment: Voted as "off topic" because the real problem was a misunderstanding about how to pass a pointer to a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
thread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &trythis, &l);
```

It passes the address of local variable `l` which is of type `list*`, so that `trythis` function gets `list**` and incorrectly casts it to `list*`.

Pass `l` by value instead:

```
thread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &trythis, l);
```

Comment: @FraPapas Alternatively, allocate `l` on the stack `list l;` and remove that `delete l;`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make sure the data you're passing in is valid over the lifetime of the threads? If it's destroyed before the threads are done using it, that would lead to undefined behavior.

The last argument to `pthread_create` is simply a convenience when you want to re-use the same `start_routine` with different arguments. Threads can shared data simply by referencing the same variables.